# Audio pause is not working where play working fine

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to implement this method because I have a table of audio to `play/pause` individually, so I found this way after many research. But pause is not working here. Could anyone please help me?

```js
function playAudio(url) {
        new Audio(url).play();
      }
function pauseAudio(url) {
        new Audio(url).pause();
      }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="playAudio('https://cldup.com/qR72ozoaiQ.mp3')" />         
<input type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="pauseAudio('https://cldup.com/qR72ozoaiQ.mp3')" />
```

Comment: You should check the audio html tag. Currently everytime u click, a new object is generated which is not the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the play/pause event to the audio tag (you can do it by setting an id to your audio element so you can target it for example) : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause

```
function playAudio(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).play();
}
function pauseAudio(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).pause();
}
```

```
<audio
    id='sound' 
    controls
    src="https://cldup.com/qR72ozoaiQ.mp3">
    Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
<input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="playAudio('sound')" />         
<input type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="pauseAudio('sound')" />
```

Comment: Can we make this function dynamic? if we have 10 or more songs, this play and pause will work for all.

Comment: Yes you can by setting different ids and sending them as a parameter so the js part can be used for as many audio tag you want (see my updated code).

Answer (score 1):

You have created two objects so it does not pause the same object.

```js
let audio =new Audio();
function playAudio(url) {
   audio.src =url;
   audio.play();
}
function pauseAudio() {
    audio.pause();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="PLAY" onclick="playAudio('https://cldup.com/qR72ozoaiQ.mp3')" />         
<input type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="pauseAudio()" />
```

Comment: @SatyabrataSahoo I have updated my answer to the same functionality for 10 songs or more.

Comment: finally this worked for me.... Happy now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question. If I am playing two songs at a time, then pause is not working, Any solution for this?